# How to get data and binding data from onMounted VueJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Test.vue

```
<template>
  <li v-for="item in masterCompany" v-bind:key="item.id">
    {{ item.displayName }}
  </li>
</template>
<script>
import Test from "../hooks/Test.hook";
import { onMounted } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const { getCompanysService, masterCompany } = Test.onLoadCompanys();
    onMounted(getCompanysService);
    return {
      getCompanysService,
      masterCompany,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Test.hook.js

```
import MasterService from '../services/masters.service'
import {reactive} from 'vue' 
function LoadCompanys() { 
    let masterCompany = reactive([])
    const getCompanysService = async () => 
        { 
            masterCompany.value = await MasterService.getCompanys();
        }
    return  {
        masterCompany,
        getCompanysService
    }
}

export default {  
    onLoadCompanys : LoadCompanys
};
```

master.service.js

```
    import HttpRequest from './api.service' 
    let http = new HttpRequest(); 
    export const Masters = { 
        async getCompanys(){ 
            let url = 'https://Test.com/GetCompany';
            return await http.get(url).then((res) => { 
               console.log('getCompanys',res)
                return res.data;
            })
    }
} 
export default Masters
```

I tried to get data from api so but I don't know to binding in components

components does not show value.

Or is there a better way to do this? Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`masterCompany` should be defined as `ref` or a nested field in an object passed to`reactive` :

```
import MasterService from '../services/masters.service'
import {ref} from 'vue' 
function LoadCompanys() { 
    let masterCompany = ref([])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is there another way to mapping model?

Comment: you're welcome, you could use `reactive` like : `const state = reactive({masterCompany :[]})` then use `state.masterCompany` instead of `masterCompany.value`